# Auto update function definition

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Does Eclipse support automatic update of the function definition based on a function call we are trying to implement?

Example:

```
My_func_abc(this_exists_in_definition, this_does_not);
```

So the definition would go from:

```
My_func_abc( Type_of_var this_exists_in_definition);
```

To:

```
My_func_abc( Type_of_var this_exists_in_definition, Type_of_var this_does_not);
```

Comment: Off topic: I'm not sure I'd like this behaviour. How is the IDE supposed to know you are not simply trying to make an overload unrelated to an existing prototype?

Comment: If Eclipse did this by default, I probably would have found it by now. Looking under Window->Preferences->C/C++->Editor->Content  Assist for an option to switch on I can't find anything that reads like it provides this functionality.

Comment: Eclipse supports this for Java (using Quick-fixes), but not for C/C++. Contributions welcome.